# Are there many examples of stable, well characterised organometallic compounds of saturated hydrocarbons with beta hydrogens?

Tags: organometallic-compounds

One of the first things you tend to learn in organometallic chemistry is that **transition metal** compounds containing beta-hydrogens are unstable (there are plenty of stable main groups ones; eg grignards seem pretty stable for most saturated aliphatics). There is a tendency for the beta hydrogen on the alkane to be abstracted by the transition metal leaving a metal hydride and a coordinated alkene, possibly followed by other reactions.

Aryl and alkene ligands are mostly immune to this reaction for various reasons. Similar hydrocarbon ligand with no beta hydrogens are usually much more stable.

But are there any well characterised examples of stable transition metal organometallics with beta hydrogens?

Comment: Are you asking only about  transition metal compounds? Then you should highlight is as there's plenty of main group organometallics where there's no such tendency.

Comment: @Mithoron Good point. I've clarified.

Comment: Zinc compounds are pretty stable. Isopropyl zinc bromide is commercially available.

Comment: @Waylander Zinc isn't considered a transition metal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_12_element#Classification